# How to produce error message when user click on the button in php?

Tags: php

I'm creating a function where user cannot claim today's money transaction in their account. But still can view their today's transaction. So I wanted to create a message to inform user that if user want's to claim their today's transaction, they cannot do that. They will have to comeback tomorrow if they want. This is what I'have tried but it's not working and it did not show the message.
I'm trying to display the message of `Comeback tomorrow!`

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("lolo", "hahaha", "", "eh");
$ql = "UPDATE kola SET setatus ='upgrade' WHERE ID = 'opopo1' AND 
DATE(date) !=CURRENT_DATE() ";
$ql_claim = mysqli_query($connection, $ql);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($ql_claim) > 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Successful!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location = 'nextPage.php'</script>";
} else
    echo "<script>alert('Comeback tomorrow!')</script>";
}
```

I wanted to display the `Comeback tomorrow` alert but my alert are not working.

Comment: Shouldn't `$ql_claim = mysqli_query($connection,$ql_claim);` be `$ql_claim = mysqli_query($connection,$ql);`?

Comment: yeah don't worry about that I forgot to edit the code here, yeah it supposed to be like that. but i still don't get the alert message .

Comment: Try `var_dump(mysqli_affected_rows($ql_claim))` and see what it's actually getting. I'm assuming that you're seeing the `Successful!` alert?

Comment: @waima, does my answer is working or not please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is an curly bracket `{` is missing in your code after `else` condition, so I updated your code.

```
$conn = new mysqli("lolo","hahaha","", "eh");
$status = "upgrade";
$id = "opopo1";
$ql_claim = $conn->prepare("UPDATE kola SET setatus = ? WHERE ID = ? AND DATE(date) != CURRENT_DATE()");
$ql_claim->bind_param("ss", $status, $id);
$ql_claim->execute();
if($ql_claim->affected_rows > 0 ) {
    echo "<script>
             alert('Successful!');
             window.location = 'nextPage.php';
          </script>";  
}
else{
    echo "<script>
             alert('Comeback tomorrow!');
         </script>";
}
```

**Note:** Please always use Prepared statements while Selecting, Updating, Inserting, or Deleting query in MySQL to avoid SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Also their script is not vulnerable to SQL injection as there are no variable values. Whether this is their real code or only static ids / values being used is a question though.

Comment: @Jonnix, But in this case there is an extra bracket, which may cause an error to be thrown

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, it's probably a mistake / extra c+p bit, but good catch.

Comment: it's not working. It did not showed me the alert for `Comeback Tomorrow`

Comment: @waima, I think you didn't getting your expected output just because of `$mysqli->affected_rows`, try an alternative way or share your table structure to us to solve your problem.